# How can I reset all folds to the state when the editor started?

Tags: folding

I have some configuration in my `.vimrc` governing the initial folding strategy. Sometimes, I am looking to restore the initial state and would like a `:refold` command or something, which restores the initial state.

Is there some built-in way to do this?

Comment: Doesn't `:e!` do what you want?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt This does not seem to work. Rather something like `:enew | e#`. But I doubt it should be recommended.

Comment: @Matt `:e!` has always reset the folds for me. not sure why you would recommend opening the same file in a different window so.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Perhaps, you make use only of `za` and other such commands which influence only individual folds, but not any of the window folding options. But if you ever use `zR`, or something like that, then its effect of setting local `foldlevel` will remain after `:e!`

Comment: @Matt I guess that depends on your modeline setting :) But I do not use folding much indeed.

Comment: Also `zX` might be helpful.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Well, if all local options are properly reset in the modeline, then `:e!` should work okay.

Answer (score 1):

> would like a :refold command`

```
command! -range -addr=windows Refold call ResetWinOpts(<line1>, <line2>, ['fdm', 'fdl', ...])
command! RefoldAll tabdo %Refold

" reset options through a window-range to global values
function! ResetWinOpts(winid1, winid2, opts)
    call execute(printf("%s,%swindo setl %s<", a:winid1, a:winid2, join(a:opts, "< ")))
endfunction
```

If you're only interested in undoing all effects of manual folding, like `za/zo/zc` etc. then, as @ChristianBrabandt suggested in the comments, the command `zX` will do this for you.